# How can I prevent SQL injection using foreach to insert multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

On the client side, the user can specify categories (think menu categories like Appetizers, Entrees, Desserts). My goal is to store these categories in my database. My code works but I fear the $category is vulnerable to SQL injection. I know how to prevent injection with a single variable like :business_id, but how would I do this when there can be multiple values ($category)? Thank you for any help.

```
                    function recreate_categories_for_business($business_id, $categories) {                            
                        $categories = json_decode(stripslashes($categories));

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO Categories (business_id, name) VALUES ";
                        foreach($categories as $category) {
                            $sql .= "(:business_id, '".$category."'),";     
                        }
                        $sql = rtrim($sql, ",");


                        if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
                            $stmt->bindParam(':business_id', $business_id);
                            if($stmt->execute()) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Dont insert them all at once. Just bind the category as a placeholder, foreach the categories and execute the prepared stmt multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [PDOStatement::bindValue](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), simply use `?` instead of `:business_id` and the category value in the query and an integer (starting with 1) to bind the value. Like so:

```
function recreate_categories_for_business($business_id, $categories) {                            
    $categories = json_decode(stripslashes($categories));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Categories (business_id, name) VALUES ";
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $sql .= "(?, ?),";     
    }
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ",");


    if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $i++; // update position for the business ID (starting with 1)
            $stmt->bindValue($i, $business_id);
            $i++; // update the position for the category name
            $stmt->bindValue($i, $category);
        }
        if($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```